# Asymptotics for $\sum\frac{1}{1+\log (x/p)}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I would like an asymptotic estimate for $$\sum_{p\leqslant x}\frac{1}{1+\log (x/p)},$$where $p$ always represents a prime number.

I tried making a Stieltjes integral out of the sum and evaluate it, but it didn't really work out. Any ideas?

Comment: In the title it looks like $\log(x+1)$, but in the body rather $\log(x)+1$?

Comment: Yes, $x$ and $1$ are separate, thanks for pointing out. I made it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting it to an integral is a good idea. Indeed, we have
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{1+\log (x/p)} =\pi (x) - \int_2^x {\frac{{\pi (t)}}{{(1 + \log (x/t))^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{t}} .
$$
We shall estimate the integral. By the prime number theorem
$$
\pi (t) = \frac{t}{{\log t}} + \mathcal{O} \bigg( {\frac{t}{{\log ^2 t}}} \bigg),
$$
and hence
\begin{align*}
\int_2^x {\frac{{\pi (t)}}{{(1 + \log (x/t))^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{t}} &= \int_2^x {\frac{1}{{(1 + \log (x/t))^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\log t}}}  + \mathcal{O} (1)\int_2^x {\frac{1}{{(1 + \log (x/t))^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\log ^2 t}}} 
\\ & = \int_2^x {\frac{1}{{(1 + \log (x/t))^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\log t}}}  + \mathcal{O} \bigg( {\frac{x}{{\log ^2 x}}} \bigg).
\end{align*}
The estimate for the second integral may be shown by splitting the range of integration at $t=\sqrt{x}$ and estimating the two integrals separately. To estimate the first integral, we perform a change of variables from $t$ to $s$ via $t = x/s$:
$$
\int_2^x {\frac{1}{{(1 + \log (x/t))^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\log t}}}  = \frac{x}{{\log x}}\int_1^{x/2} {\frac{1}{{(1 + \log s)^2 }}\frac{1}{{s^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{1 - \log s/\log x}}} .
$$
By the dominated convergence theorem
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \int_1^{x/2} {\frac{1}{{(1 + \log s)^2 }}\frac{1}{{s^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{1 - \log s/\log x}}}  = \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{(1 + \log s)^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{s^2 }}} =\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - t} }}{{(1 + t)^2 }}{\rm d}t},
$$
where in the second step we made a change of variables from $s$ to $t$ via $s={\rm e}^t$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{1+\log (x/p)} \sim \pi (x) - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - t} }}{{(1 + t)^2 }}{\rm d}t}\cdot \frac{x}{{\log x}}
$$
as $x\to +\infty$. Finally, since via integration by parts,
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - t} }}{{(1 + t)^2 }}{\rm d}t}  = 1 - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - t} }}{{1 + t}}{\rm d}t} 
$$
and by the prime number theorem $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$, we can write
$$\boxed{
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{1+\log (x/p)} \sim c\, \frac{x}{{\log x}}}
$$
as $x\to+\infty$, with
$$
c=\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - t} }}{{1 + t}}{\rm d}t} =0.596347362323194\ldots \,.
$$
This constant $c$ is sometimes called the [Gompertz constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_constant).

**Addendum.** With the aid of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/311085),
$$
\frac{1}{{\pi (x)}}\sum\limits_{p \le x} {\frac{1}{{1 - \log (p/x)}}}  \to \int_0^1 {\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{1 - \log s}}}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - t} }}{{1 + t}}{\rm d}s} .
$$